# Add sequence id for groupby column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement that to add a sequence id for groupby column.
The original Dataset is like this:

```
+------------+-----------------+-------+
|   appId|                  rpc|elapsed|
+------------+-----------------+-------+
|     account|/rpc1            |      7|
|     service|/rpc4            |      0|
|     service|/rpc5            |      0|
|     account|/rpc1            |     78|
|         api|/rpc2            |     87|
|         api|/rpc2            |     52|
|     service|/rpc4            |      0|
|         api|/rpc3            |     52|
|     service|/rpc4            |      1|
|     service|/rpc4            |      0|
|     service|/rpc5            |      0|
+------------+-----------------+-------+
```

After doing a `dataset.select("appId", "rpc","elapsed").orderby("appId", "rpc","elapsed").show`

```
+------------+-----------------+-------+
|   appId|                  rpc|elapsed| 
+------------+-----------------+-------+
|     account|/rpc1            |      7| 
|     account|/rpc1            |     78|  
|         api|/rpc2            |     87| 
|         api|/rpc2            |     52|  
|         api|/rpc3            |     52| 
|     service|/rpc4            |      0|
|     service|/rpc4            |      1|  
|     service|/rpc4            |      0|  
|     service|/rpc4            |      0| 
|     service|/rpc5            |      0|  
|     service|/rpc5            |      0|  
+------------+-----------------+-------+
```

I want to add an ***id column*** for the groupbyed result as following

```
+------------+-----------------+-------+---+
|   appId|                  rpc|elapsed| id|
+------------+-----------------+-------+---+
|     account|/rpc1            |      7|  1|
|     account|/rpc1            |     78|  2|
|         api|/rpc2            |     87|  1|
|         api|/rpc2            |     52|  2|
|         api|/rpc3            |     52|  1|
|     service|/rpc4            |      0|  1|
|     service|/rpc4            |      1|  2|
|     service|/rpc4            |      0|  3|
|     service|/rpc4            |      0|  4|
|     service|/rpc5            |      0|  1|
|     service|/rpc5            |      0|  2|
+------------+-----------------+-------+---+
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can such an id using window functions:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number

dataset
.withColumn("id",row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("appId","rpc").orderBy("elapsed"))
.show
```